# Online radio for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, streaming, proxy, radio

**Must have:**

- Support for web proxy access
- Possibility to load custom streams

**Should have:**

- Understandable UI
- But only command line is also option
- Possibility to also play local sources

**Nice to have:**

- Software already knows popular radio stations from Czech Republic

**Software tried but not working:**

- Rhythmbox - cannot open the stream
- Radio Tray - cannot work through proxy
- Audacious - cannot open the stream

(but I maybe just did not realise how to setup the proxy in the software)